# $\int _a^b\:\left|\cos x\right|dx\:,\:\int _a^b\:\left|\sin x\right|dx\:,\:\int _a^b\:\left|\tan x\right|dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, area, absolute-value

I understand how to find the area in equations with quadratics and linear, but how would I approach with trig in terms of splitting the integrals?

for example $\int _0^{2\pi }\:\left|\left(\sin x\right)\right|dx$

Comment: What do you mean by "splitting the integral"? Also, all your integrals are from $n$ to $n$, which would mean they are always 0.

Comment: for example $\int _0^{2\pi }\:\left|\left(sinx\right)\right|dx$

i think you have to split from 0 to $\pi $ then $\pi $ to 2$\pi $

how do you recognize this

Comment: Because that is where $\sin(x)$ changes sign. If you split it into integrals from 0 to $\pi$ and $\pi$ to $2\pi$ you can get rid of the absolute value.

Comment: you need to start by finding the ranges over which the function is negative, then splitting the integral up into the sum of those ranges, then you can remove the absolute value by modifying the integrals as needed - can you work out $\int _{\pi}^{2\pi }\:\left|\left(sinx\right)\right|dx$ for example - how might you do that?

Comment: how about $\int _{-1}^{1} |x|dx$ could you do that one?  What considerations does it require - you could do it in two halfs right?